# Flex: preventDefault on spark:ListBase not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, preventdefault

The proposed UX I am trying to achieve is this:

1. user clicks menu item (via a listBase subclass: e.g. ButtonBar or TabBar)
2. prevent initial selection
3. validate if user needs to address issues (e.g. unsaved data on a form, etc.)
4. if valid, take selection and set the listBase to that selectedIndex, otherwise present warnings to user and cancel out the selection process altogether

This does not work as you'd expect.  Utilizing the IndexChangeEvent.CHANGING type and the preventDefault works to kill the selection, but at step 4, when I am programmatically setting the selectedIndex of the listBase, it then tries to redispatch the CHANGING event (this despite what the API docs claim).

Here is a sample application src code if you'd like to try this for yourself.  I look forward to your comments & solutions.

Thanks.
J

http://snipt.org/vUji3#expand

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
           xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.utils.setTimeout;

        import mx.core.mx_internal;

        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

        use namespace mx_internal;

        [Bindable]
        private var doPreventDefault:Boolean;

        [Bindable]
        private var delayMS:uint = 500;

        private function buttonbar_changingHandler( event:IndexChangeEvent ):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if ( doPreventDefault )
            {
                event.preventDefault();

                setTimeout( delayedLogic, delayMS, event.newIndex );
            }
        }

        private function delayedLogic( index:int ):void
        {
            //disabling this results in an endless loop of trying to set the selected index
            //              doPreventDefault = false;

            //this should NOT be hitting the changing handler since we're supposed to be dispatching a value commit event instead.
            bb.setSelectedIndex( index, false );
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>

    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center"/>
</s:layout>

<s:ButtonBar id="bb"
             changing="buttonbar_changingHandler(event)">
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <fx:String>btn 0</fx:String>
            <fx:String>btn 1</fx:String>
            <fx:String>btn 2</fx:String>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:ButtonBar>

<s:CheckBox label="preventDefault?"
            selected="@{ doPreventDefault }"/>

<s:NumericStepper maximum="5000" minimum="500"
                  stepSize="500" value="@{ delayMS }"/>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Unfortunately only events that are marked cancelable can be prevented - and that's only if the event listener itself is looking for the isDefaultPrevented() flag and hopefully returning out of it. The changing event isn't one of them.

Comment: @MikePetty Yes it is: it is both cancelable and preventable (if that is even a word). As the OP describes the issue lies not in the preventing, but rather in the unexpected dispatching of an event in 'step 4'.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do with that `delayedLogic` thingy: given your UX requirements you should simply prevent the event if the user input is invalid and do nothing (i.e. let the List do what it's supposed to do) when the user input is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the SDK, the `IndexChangeEvent.CHANGING` event is actually preventable - despite the documentation [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ListBase.html#event:changing) says that cancelable is false, so my bad on that (although ASDoc went a little sideways), however things get a little interesting from here.

In ListBase @1296 this is only ever dispatched from the `commitSelection(dispatchEvents:Boolean = true)` method. In `ButtonBarBase:dataProvider_changeHandler()` is the only place that specifically calls to not dispatch the event, but in `ListBase`, it's called in `commitProperties` @939 when there is a proposedSelectionIndex.

So from your code above, if you are trying to set the selection - this is going to call the commitSelection, which I believe is causing the call stack issue. The Timer delay is just going to exacerbate the issue, since at 500ms the UI will have gone through its invalidation cycle at least once, meaning the commitSelection will be executed again because of an `invalidateProperties` flag is being set from the `proprosedSelectionIndex` eventually stemming from `setSelectedIndex` @729

So how to fix this.

 I would look at only doing the prevent if the validation fails, otherwise allow it to proceed as normal. If it does fail, call the prevent, set an `errorString` or equivalent, but don't attempt to change the selection.

[edit] Read RiaStar's comment, and I just concurred with the same 'solution'.

Comment: the reason I had the delay in there was to provide a sense of logic behind the scenes doing some sort of validation before allowing/canceling the requested index change.